# Segmentation fault (core dumped) if index iterates in reverse

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, coredump

I have a very simple piece of code and it reads characters from files. If the index `y` iterates from low to high, everything works. But, if it iterates from high to low (the commented line), it gives me the seg fault problem. Could someone explain why this happens? Thank you!

```
void read_ct_from_file( unsigned char** ct, const size_t row, const size_t column, FILE* inf ) {
    size_t x, y;
    for( x = 0; x < row; x++ ) {
        for( y = 0; y < column; y++ ) { 
        //for( y = column - 1; y >= 0; y-- ) { // iterate from high to low

              fscanf( inf, "%02x", &ct[x][y] );
              printf( "%02x ", ct[x][y] );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`size_t` is unsigned, so your loop will after `y = 0` continue with `max_unsigned` which is >= 0.

Comment: I dont quite understand your explanation, could you please elaborate? So the loop will continue after y = 0? it will go to y = -1?

Comment: No, not -1; size_t is an unsigned int, thus never negative. After y=0, y is 2^32-1

Comment: In order to understand Stefan's comment, you must understand [overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). With an unsigned integer, you overflow when you go less than 0.

Comment: @Stefan, I understand now, the loop index goes out of bound at the last iteration. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

BTW a good way to have both the unsigned size_t index **and** avoid the wraparound underflow is this construct:

```
void read_ct_from_file( unsigned char** ct, const size_t row, const size_t column, FILE* inf ) {
    size_t x, y;
    for( x = 0; x < row; x++ ) {
        for ( y = column; y-- > 0; ) { // iterate from high to low

              fscanf( inf, "%02x", &ct[x][y] );
              printf( "%02x ", ct[x][y] );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```

Comment: I already accept an answer. But thank you so much for the new tips!

Answer (score -1):

```
for( y = column - 1; y > 0; y-- ) { // iterate from high to low
```

try with this.

Comment: What about when index y is 0? That is the last element in the array.

Comment: they probably mean `for (y = column; y > 0; y--) ...` and then use `y - 1` everywhere.